# transparent parts of GIF/PNG image shown in black inside a JLabel java

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jlabel

I have an image (gif or png) with some transparents parts which appear in black when put inside a JLabel.

```
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("resources/myPicture.png"));
    label = new JLabel(img);
```

How do I work around this problem ?

I do not need the JLabel, maybe there is a better way to display the image correctly (i.e. with the transparency) directly on a JPanel ?

Thanks
David

Comment: Are you sure that the JLabel is at fault, that the picture isn't transparent or that the background isn't black?  As far as I understand things, what you desire should work for an image in a JLabel.

Comment: the picture *is* transparent and shows up correctly on a browser for instance.

Comment: @Hovercraft: I think you meant "picture *is* transparent".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the culprit !

Actually the picture is getting rescaled before being added to the JLabel and for that, I used BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB instead of BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB

I really didn't think that the rescaling method could alter this (silly me!), that's why I didn't show it in the code I added to the question...

David

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, for solving the mystery! Obviously, none of us could have figured it out, unless you had posted an SSCCE to begin with (similar to my example above), something to keep in mind for future problems

Answer (score 3):

Again, are you sure that it's the JLabel's fault?  When I tried to do a proof of concept program, everything worked fine -- the background JPanel's pink color was seen.  e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransparentJLabel {
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "http://duke.kenai.com/Oracle/OracleStratSmall.png";

    private static void createAndShowUI() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.pink);

        URL imageUrl;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(IMAGE_PATH);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            panel.add(label);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TransparentJLabel");
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You may wish to create a similar program yourself to see if and where your problem is, and then post it here.

Comment: thanks, that helped me to find the culprit (see my own answer)