# Java: Animated GIFs go automatically partially transparent

Tags: java, swing, gif, animated-gif

I would like to display a wait dialog with an animated GIF using Java Swing, but the GIFs are displayed incorrectly.

**Code Example:**

```
final JDialog progressDialog = new JDialog(new Frame(), "...", true);

URL url =  getClass().getResource("wait.gif");
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

progressDialog.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (0, 200, 200));
progressDialog.getContentPane().add(label);
progressDialog.pack();
progressDialog.setVisible(true);
```

**Original GIF is here:**

[image]

**But the Java output looks like this:**

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Also posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36671767/2891664), probably the same issue. I couldn't reproduce it but I'm stuck on Java 6 right now because of hardware issues with my other computer. Same thing I said to the other poster, an MCVE is extremely helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694343/2891664. Again, MCVE, very helpful.

Comment: @Radiodef Thanks for the post, I did not notice it (the same problem and today... unbelievable).

Comment: @Radiodef The http://stackoverflow.com/a/4694343/2891664 is a little different problem (transparent areas are black and it's a static GIF). Here the black areas are transparent (and not only black color is affected, if the GIF is for example red, the "solid red" is also transparent). Standard static GIFs are displayed correctly, as well as first frame of the animated GIF.

Comment: Yes that's fair enough; however, part of the point of the link is to illustrate the value in an MCVE. I couldn't reproduce this issue, but I had to write my own program to test it and maybe you and the other poster (who never did post an MCVE) are doing something different. And if I still can't reproduce it, an MCVE also saves time for any of the other Swing people who see your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ever you have these types of problems, you want to start playing around with the `disposalMethod` of the frames.

I ran your gif through some inspection code and found the `disposalMethod` to be set to `RESTORE_TO_BACKGROUND`

So, basically, I took your gif and ran it through the following code, which created a new gif with the `disposalMethod` of `none`

[image: Example]

So your original image is on top and the "fixed" image is on the bottom

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataNode;
import javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class MirrorImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MirrorImage();
    }

    public MirrorImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private ImageIcon orig;
        private ImageIcon mirror;

        public TestPane() {
            mirror(new File("Qzlxj.gif"), new File("Test.gif"));
            orig = new ImageIcon("Qzlxj.gif");
            mirror = new ImageIcon("Test.gif");
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return mirror == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(orig.getIconWidth(), orig.getIconHeight() * 2);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (orig != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                int x = (getWidth() - orig.getIconWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - (orig.getIconHeight() * 2)) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(orig.getImage(), x, y, this);

//                AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
//                at.setToScale(1, -1);
//                at.translate(0, -mirror.getIconHeight());
//                g2d.setTransform(at);
                g2d.drawImage(mirror.getImage(), x, y + mirror.getIconHeight(), this);
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void mirror(File source, File dest) {

        List<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<>(25);
        List<Integer> delays = new ArrayList<>(25);
        int delay = 0;

        ImageOutputStream output = null;
        GifSequenceWriter writer = null;

        try {

            String[] imageatt = new String[]{
                "imageLeftPosition",
                "imageTopPosition",
                "imageWidth",
                "imageHeight"
            };

            ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("gif").next();
            ImageInputStream ciis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
            reader.setInput(ciis, false);
            int noi = reader.getNumImages(true);
            BufferedImage master = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < noi; i++) {

                BufferedImage image = reader.read(i);
                IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(i);

                Node tree = metadata.getAsTree("javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0");
                NodeList children = tree.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < children.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node nodeItem = children.item(j);
                    System.out.println(nodeItem.getNodeName());
                    if (nodeItem.getNodeName().equals("ImageDescriptor")) {
                        Map<String, Integer> imageAttr = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                        NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes();
//                        for (int index = 0; index < attr.getLength(); index++) {
//                            Node node = attr.item(index);
//                            System.out.println("----> " + node.getNodeName() + "=" + node.getNodeValue());
//                        }
                        for (int k = 0; k < imageatt.length; k++) {
                            Node attnode = attr.getNamedItem(imageatt[k]);
                            imageAttr.put(imageatt[k], Integer.valueOf(attnode.getNodeValue()));
                        }

                        if (master == null) {
                            master = new BufferedImage(imageAttr.get("imageWidth"), imageAttr.get("imageHeight"), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                        }

                        Graphics2D g2d = master.createGraphics();
                        g2d.drawImage(image, imageAttr.get("imageLeftPosition"), imageAttr.get("imageTopPosition"), null);
                        g2d.dispose();

//                        BufferedImage frame = mirror(copyImage(master));
                        BufferedImage frame = copyImage(master);
                        ImageIO.write(frame, "png", new File("img" + i + ".png"));
                        images.add(frame);

                    } else if (nodeItem.getNodeName().equals("GraphicControlExtension")) {
                        NamedNodeMap attr = nodeItem.getAttributes();
                        Node delayNode = attr.getNamedItem("delayTime");
                        if (delayNode != null) {
                            delay = Math.max(delay, Integer.valueOf(delayNode.getNodeValue()));
                            delays.add(delay);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            output = new FileImageOutputStream(dest);
            writer = new GifSequenceWriter(output, images.get(0).getType(), delay * 10, true);

            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                BufferedImage nextImage = images.get(i);
                writer.writeToSequence(nextImage);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            try {
                output.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage mirror(BufferedImage img) {

        BufferedImage mirror = createCompatibleImage(img);
        Graphics2D g2d = mirror.createGraphics();
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.setToScale(1, -1);
        at.translate(0, -img.getHeight());
        g2d.setTransform(at);
        g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return mirror;

    }

    public static BufferedImage copyImage(BufferedImage img) {
        int width = img.getWidth();
        int height = img.getHeight();

        BufferedImage newImage = createCompatibleImage(img);
        Graphics graphics = newImage.createGraphics();

        int x = (width - img.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (height - img.getHeight()) / 2;

        graphics.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), null);
        graphics.dispose();

        return newImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createCompatibleImage(BufferedImage image) {
        return getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), image.getTransparency());
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
        return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static class GifSequenceWriter {

        protected ImageWriter gifWriter;
        protected ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam;
        protected IIOMetadata imageMetaData;

        /**
         * Creates a new GifSequenceWriter
         *
         * @param outputStream the ImageOutputStream to be written to
         * @param imageType one of the imageTypes specified in BufferedImage
         * @param timeBetweenFramesMS the time between frames in miliseconds
         * @param loopContinuously wether the gif should loop repeatedly
         * @throws IIOException if no gif ImageWriters are found
         *
         * @author Elliot Kroo (elliot[at]kroo[dot]net)
         */
        public GifSequenceWriter(
                ImageOutputStream outputStream,
                int imageType,
                int timeBetweenFramesMS,
                boolean loopContinuously) throws IIOException, IOException {
            // my method to create a writer
            gifWriter = getWriter();
            imageWriteParam = gifWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
            ImageTypeSpecifier imageTypeSpecifier
                    = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(imageType);

            imageMetaData
                    = gifWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageTypeSpecifier,
                            imageWriteParam);

            String metaFormatName = imageMetaData.getNativeMetadataFormatName();

            IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) imageMetaData.getAsTree(metaFormatName);

            IIOMetadataNode graphicsControlExtensionNode = getNode(
                    root,
                    "GraphicControlExtension");

            //restoreToBackgroundColor
            //restoreToPrevious
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "transparentColorFlag",
                    "FALSE");
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "delayTime",
                    Integer.toString(timeBetweenFramesMS / 10));
            graphicsControlExtensionNode.setAttribute(
                    "transparentColorIndex",
                    "0");

            IIOMetadataNode commentsNode = getNode(root, "CommentExtensions");
            commentsNode.setAttribute("CommentExtension", "Created by MAH");

            IIOMetadataNode appEntensionsNode = getNode(
                    root,
                    "ApplicationExtensions");

            IIOMetadataNode child = new IIOMetadataNode("ApplicationExtension");

            child.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
            child.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");

            int loop = loopContinuously ? 0 : 1;

            child.setUserObject(new byte[]{0x1, (byte) (loop & 0xFF), (byte) ((loop >> 8) & 0xFF)});
            appEntensionsNode.appendChild(child);

            imageMetaData.setFromTree(metaFormatName, root);

            gifWriter.setOutput(outputStream);

            gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
        }

        public void writeToSequence(RenderedImage img) throws IOException {
            gifWriter.writeToSequence(
                    new IIOImage(
                            img,
                            null,
                            imageMetaData),
                    imageWriteParam);
        }

        /**
         * Close this GifSequenceWriter object. This does not close the
         * underlying stream, just finishes off the GIF.
         */
        public void close() throws IOException {
            gifWriter.endWriteSequence();
        }

        /**
         * Returns the first available GIF ImageWriter using
         * ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif").
         *
         * @return a GIF ImageWriter object
         * @throws IIOException if no GIF image writers are returned
         */
        private static ImageWriter getWriter() throws IIOException {
            Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("gif");
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                throw new IIOException("No GIF Image Writers Exist");
            } else {
                return iter.next();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns an existing child node, or creates and returns a new child
         * node (if the requested node does not exist).
         *
         * @param rootNode the <tt>IIOMetadataNode</tt> to search for the child
         * node.
         * @param nodeName the name of the child node.
         *
         * @return the child node, if found or a new node created with the given
         * name.
         */
        private static IIOMetadataNode getNode(
                IIOMetadataNode rootNode,
                String nodeName) {
            int nNodes = rootNode.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < nNodes; i++) {
                if (rootNode.item(i).getNodeName().compareToIgnoreCase(nodeName)
                        == 0) {
                    return ((IIOMetadataNode) rootNode.item(i));
                }
            }
            IIOMetadataNode node = new IIOMetadataNode(nodeName);
            rootNode.appendChild(node);
            return (node);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the "fixed" gif

[image: Fixed]

The above is based on the investigations from [Mirroring animated gif on load in Java - ImageIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117283/mirroring-animated-gif-on-load-in-java-imageicon/18117326#18117326)